# Extract artist and music From text (regex)

Tags: python, regex

I have written following `regex` But its not working. Can you please help me? thank you :-)

```
track_desc = '''<img src="http://images.raaga.com/catalog/cd/A/A0000102.jpg" align="right" border="0" width="100" height="100" vspace="4" hspace="4" />
            <p>
            </p>
            <p> Artist(s) David: <br/>
              Music: Ramana Gogula<br/>
            </p>'''
rx = "<p><\/p><p>Artist\(s\): (.*?)<br\/>Music: (.*?)<br\/><\/p>"
m = re.search(rx, track_desc)
```

Output Should be:

```
Artist(s) David
Music: Ramana Gogula
```

Comment: Seriously prefer an alternative to regex.

Comment: The obligatory reference is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I suppose with such badly formatted HTML, even a parser isn't going to help you too much, although you may as well use one at least for extracting the text from the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were ignoring the whitespace:

```
<p>[\s\n\r]*Artist\(s\)[\s\n\r]*(.*?)[\s\n\r]*:[\s\n\r]*<br/>[\s\n\r]*Music:[\s\n\r]*(.*?)<br/>[\s\n\r]*</p>
```

Output is:

```
[1] => "David"
[2] => "Ramana Gogula"
```

(note that your regex didn't match the `Artists(s)` and `Music:` prefixes either)

---

However **for production code I would not rely on** such rather **clumsy regex** (and equally **clumsily formatted HTML source**).

Seriously though, ditch the idea of using regex for this if you aren't the slightest familiar with regex (which it looks like). You're using the wrong tool and a badly formatted data source. Parsing HTML with Regex is wrong in 9 out of 10 cases (see @bgporter's comment link) and doomed to fail. Apart from that HTML is hardly ever an appropriate data source (unless there really really is no alternative source).

Comment: one big problem is that he's trying to match `Artist(s): David`..., while his source has the text `Artist(s) David:`...

Comment: @Regexident Thanks But It is displaying something like this. `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01FFD4E8>`

Comment: @CodeJockey: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @no_access: seriously, ditch the idea of using regex for this if you aren't the slightest familiar with regex (which it looks like). You're using the wrong tool and a badly formatted data source.

Answer (score 1):

```
import lxml.html as lh
import re

track_desc = '''
<img src="http://images.raaga.com/catalog/cd/A/A0000102.jpg" align="right" border="0" width="100" height="100" vspace="4" hspace="4" />
<p>
</p>
<p> Artist(s) David: <br/>
Music: Ramana Gogula<br/>
</p>
'''

tree = lh.fromstring(track_desc)

print re.findall(r'Artist\(s\) (.+):\s*\nMusic: (.*\w)', tree.text_content())
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few errors:

- regex is not multiline : should use `flags=re.MULTILINE` to allow to match on multilines
- spaces are not taken into account
- artist(s) is not followed by `:`

As the web page is rather strangely presented, this might be error prone to rely on a regex and I wouldn't advise to use it extensively.

Note, following seems to work:

```
rx='Artist(?:\(s\))?\s+(.*?)\<br\/>\s+Music:\s*(.*?)\<br'
print ("Art... : %s && Mus... : %s" % re.search(rx, track_desc,flags=re.MULTILINE).groups())
```